# Unable to create a reference to a new instance of a class

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm new to C++ and is trying to learn the concept of pointer and references. I tried to create a reference and a pointer to a new instance of a class using the statement below

```
Animal *rA = new Animal();//works fine

Animal &rA = new Animal();//compiler prints error: non-const lvalue reference 
                          //to type 'Animal' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Animal *'
```

Due to my limited knowledge, I am unable to understand the error message printed out by the compiler. Could someone please kindly explain it to me what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` returns a pointer. A reference must be initialized with the actual object, not a pointer to the object.

```
Animal &rA = * new Animal;
```

..would work, but until you know what you're doing, you generally shouldn't be using `new`.

```
Animal A;
Animal &rA = A;
```

...works without getting into nastiness you should be staying away from.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! really helped my understanding.